# プレイヤーにアニメーション（歩く様子）がつけられないがエラーも出ない

Tags: swift4, spritekit

以下の記事をとても参考にさせていただきつつ、
https://qiita.com/yamajyn/items/3436d650a6e7b6fc759e
自機に動きをつけたいと考え、自機クラス(Player)のinit関数内に以下のようにアトラスを作成しています。
Assetフォルダの中ではしっかりとTextureSetとして３枚がひとまとまりのフォルダになっていますし、あまりにも自然にビルドも通っています。
しかし、アニメーションが機能しません。
こういった時は大抵、アニメーションの宣言をする場所が端から間違っていたりすることが多いのですが……わかりません。
どなたか、教えていただけると幸いです。
また、printを用いてtexturesの配列の中身も確認しましたが、問題なく意図した通りのファイル名が整然としており、ファイル名ミスはあまり考えられません。

```
 init(def_pos: CGPoint) {
        var textures: [SKTexture] = []
        let atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "jelly")
        for i in 1...3 {
            textures.append(atlas.textureNamed("jelly" + String(i)))
        }

        super.init(texture: textures[2], color: NSColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        self.position = def_pos

        let animation = SKAction.animate(withNormalTextures: textures, timePerFrame: 1.0)
        self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(animation))
}
```

Comment: `class func animate(with textures: [SKTexture], timePerFrame sec: TimeInterval) -> SKAction`を使わずに、`class func animate(withNormalTextures textures: [SKTexture], timePerFrame sec: TimeInterval) -> SKAction`を使用する理由はなんでしょうか？引用先のサンプルコードでも、（Swiftのバージョンが異なるので、構文に違いがありますが）前者を使用しています。ちなみに、その一点を除けば、じっさいにSpriteKitのプロジェクトを作って、アニメーションするNodeを作成できたことを、お伝えしておきます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Xcodeの補完に頼りすぎてアップデートなどで変更されたかと思いました。自分で回答を記載します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

このケースでは

```
let animation = SKAction.animate(withNormalTextures: textures, timePerFrame: 1.0)
```

は意図する動きになりません。
現バージョン（19/9/4時点）では

```
let animation = SKAction.animate(with: textures, timePerFrame: 0.2)
```

以上のように綴ります。